# Laravel Mail redirect with message ignored

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the Laravel Mail function in combination with a 
Redirect with a message but It's not catching the message

This is my controller

```
public function send(ContactFormRequest $request)
{
    \Mail::send('emails.contact',
        array(
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'msg' => $request->get('msg')
        ), function ($body) {
            $body->to(env('ADMIN_EMAIL'), env('ADMIN_NAME'))->subject('Sap Contactformulier');
        });

    return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Uw aanvraag is verzonden');
}
```

And this is my view where i'm trying to catch the message

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="message">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

## WORKING

I got it working using the following

```
@if (!empty( Session::get('success') ))
    {{ Session::get('success') }}
@endif
```

And my controller

```
return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Uw contact aanvraag is verzonden');
```

Comment: `->with('message', 'Uw aanvraag is verzonden` - this injects a variable into the view, so if you want to print it you have to do it like this `@if (!empty($message)) {{ $message }}`. If you want to pass it via session, do a `Session::set('message', 'Uw aanvraag is verzonden');` before the Redirect

Comment: Hm it's still not working.. Can't find a good way of doing this in the laravel docs either. thanks for your response

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov That's just plain wrong. There are different `with()` methods: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L29-L46

Comment: so this should be working
// controller
return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Uw aanvraag is verzonden');

// view
    if (!empty($success))
        {{ $success }}
    endif

Comment: Gah, I was thinking of `View::make()->with()`, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: I got it working, will update my answer now

Answer (score 0):

A note from Laravel Documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#basic-usage

> Note: A $message variable is always passed to e-mail views, and allows
>   the inline embedding of attachments. So, it is best to avoid passing a
>   message variable in your view payload.

Change 'message' into something else and it should work.

Comment: What you mean is that you can't pass "message" into the view itself. That gives an error. That's why I use "msg" as you can see in the mail callback

Comment: However, what your `redirect('/')->with([....])` line does is basically the same thing (passing a variable into the view).